# Using ternary in mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

Okay, so we have just started using Redux and Sagas and are using it to fetch some async data (a JsonSchema) from the server.

After fetching, the state tree looks like this:

```
{
    "forms": {
        "form-url": {
            "isLoading": false,
            "schema": { ... }
        }
    }
}
```

The reducer looks roughly like this:

```
const reducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH:
            const form = {};
            form[action.url] = {
                isFetching: true,
                schema: {},
            };
            return Object.assign({}, state, form);
        case FETCH_SUCCESS:
            const sform = {};
            sform[action.url] = {
                isFetching: false,
                schema: action.schema,
            };
            return Object.assign({}, state, sform);
    }

    return state;
}
```

Now, when mapping state to props, and the data hasn't been fetched yet, we need a ternary to make it work:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
        schema: state.forms[ownProps.sourceUrl] ? state.forms[ownProps.sourceUrl].schema : {}
    }
}
```

Even though this works, my spidey sense is telling me that this is a code smell. Is there a suggested pattern to solve the missing initial state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) to do that, it's cleaner and re usable